# having trouble updating detached entity

Tags: entity-framework

I have read quite a few posts about this, and I can't see how my situation is different, but it must be because it still doesn't update.

Basically, my method receives a detached entity in a message. I check it's key to see if it already exists. If it does not exist I add it to the database. (this works fine) If it exists I would like to update its values.

Here is my code:

```
 InteropObject clientObject = (InteropObject)message.ItemToAddUpdate;

 bool exists = context.InteropObjects.Any(o => o.GUID == clientObject.GUID);

 if (!exists)
 {
      context.InteropObjects.AddObject(clientObject);
 }
 else
 {
      context.Attach(clientObject);
      context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(clientObject).SetModified();
 }

 context.SaveChanges();
```

thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that in the old `ObjectContext` API, setting the state to `Modified` does not set the properties of the entity to `Modified`. In the `DbContext` API this is fixed internally by a call that does do that.

In the `ObjectContext` API, you can get the same effect by setting the properties of the attached entity:

```
context.Attach(clientObject);
var ose = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntry(clientObject);

// Obtain an object array containing current values
var values = new object[ose.CurrentValues.FieldCount];
ose.CurrentValues.GetValues(values);

// "Overwrite" CurrentValues by these values:
ose.CurrentValues.SetValues(values);
```

So you set the properties by the values they already have, but this triggers the state manager to mark the property as `Modified`.